# Using SET_CONTEXT and SYS_CONTEXT

Tags: plsql

I have a PL/SQL package (say package1) which contains only 1 procedure. This procedure is used for security purpose and stores the application logged in user using SET_CONTEXT method.

I have another package (say package2) which contains several procedures related to application functionality but they use the SYS_CONTEXT to get the logged in user.

Whenever I want to call package2's procedures from Java, I want package1's procedure to be executed first and then package2's procedures. The reason is I want both these calls to happen in the same database connection.

Is there a way to configure this in Oracle instead of repeating the call to package1's procedure inside each and every package2's procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your procedure in `package1` is public (i.e., declared in the package specification), and assuming your `package2` procedures have an `EXECUTE` authority on `package1`, one of the possible solutions will be using [INITIALIZING PACKAGE](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/prog2/ch16_06.htm) .

The initialization consists of all the statements following the BEGIN statement at the end of the package declaration to the END statement

Ex.

```
PACKAGE BODY package2
IS
   --All your package2 procedures

--initialization section at the end of package2:
BEGIN
   package1.procedure1();
END package2;
```

This initialization section, will be run only the first time your session uses a package2 (by using any function/procedure in it). The package will be re-initialized in the same session if it is recompiled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, I also need to pass a value as a parameter to package1.procedure1(). This value would be sent from Java while calling the other procedure. Please let me know if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is place code of package1 (package1.procedure1();) into user logon trigger or call that procedure from that trigger; please find example bellow for  trigger

```
Example: 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hr_logon_trigger
  AFTER LOGON
  ON HR.SCHEMA
BEGIN
  -- you code here or call to package1.procedure1();
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, I also need to pass a value as a parameter to package1.procedure1(). This value would be sent from Java while calling the other procedure. Please let me know if that is possible.

Comment: I think other way is if java user is doing any dml then you can write trigger on particular table and call this procedure from that trigger; no need to call this proc form code.